# json.data.totalItems == 0 not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, youtube

Using the YouTube API. Trying to get an alert("No search results") when json.data.totalItems == 0 but it just doesn't happend, nothing happens at all... when json.data.totalItems > 0 it all works fine.

Any idea to why this is?

i.e.

json.data.totalItems == 0 :
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=20&format=5&orderby=relevance&uploader=partner&q=oierjt

code:
           var url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-             results=20&format=5&orderby=rating&uploader=partner&q=" + searchinput ;

```
        var request = $.ajax({

            url: url,

            type: "GET",

            timeout: 8000,

            dataType: "json",

            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert("Something went wrong");

            },

            success: function(json) {

                var numberOfItems = json.data.items.length;
        var totalItemsAmount = json.data.totalItems;        

        if (totalItemsAmount == 0) { 
                    alert("No videos found");
                }
                else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                            alert("videos found")
                        }
                 }
```

Comment: can you show relevant code..as to how you are using it..?

Comment: Please, post your full code.

Comment: Can you also show what `JSON.stringify(json)` gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [results](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-%20results=20&format=5&orderby=rating&uploader=partner&q=fdsjklgdsajgs) -- if `totalItems` is zero, then `items` is not present at all.  You will get an exception at the line `json.data.items.length`.  You need to remove that line, or put it inside the `else` block:

```
success: function(json) {
    var totalItemsAmount = json.data.totalItems;        
    if (totalItemsAmount == 0) { 
        alert("No videos found");
    } else {
        var numberOfItems = json.data.items.length;
```